# Como ingresar coordenadas en un arreglo en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, api

Estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto para marcar posiciones en Google Maps, no sé como leer un archivo `.txt` que contiene las coordenadas de los marcadores por longitud y latitud, como ejempolo:

```
-15.432545, 6.4344523 \n
-15.563452, 6.5423455 \n
...
```

En cada linea está lo longitud y la latitud separadas por comas, después hay salto de linea para seguir a otra posición.
Alguien sabe como ingresar estos datos en un array en javascript?
Aquí adjunto el codigo de la forma en como se ingresa el marcador

```
function initMap() {
    var Bello = {
        lat: 6.34803789449,
        lng: -75.5709292724
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: Bello
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: Bello,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Comment: Esto le puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7030469/8933039

Comment: la situación es que me dieron un archivo .txt con 100000 cooredenadas,  la cosa es meter todo eso al codigo